# Why can't I remove the background-attachment property?

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

So I'm trying to remove the background attachment property with a media query at a max-width of 1024px. I'm doing this just by going `background-attachment: none` except my devtools is flashing an error and has that property crossed out? Any ideas?

https://jsfiddle.net/dfwg2nbv/1/

```js
const ham = document.querySelector('.ham-menu');
const nav = document.querySelector('nav');
const header = document.querySelector('header');
const promise = document.querySelector('.promise');
const services = document.querySelector('.services');
const testimony = document.querySelector('.testimony');

header.style.removeProperty('background-attachment');

//detect mobile
// if ("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement) {
//   removeProps(header);
//   removeProps(promise);
//   removeProps(services);
//   removeProps(testimony);
// }

ham.addEventListener('click', animateMenu);

function animateMenu() {
 nav.classList.toggle('hamburger-open');
}

// function removeProps(node) {
//  node.style.removeProperty('background-attachment');
//  node.style.removeProperty('background-size');
// }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the background using jquery:

```
$("header").css("background-image", "none");
```

Example:

https://codepen.io/seyyedmojtaba72/pen/gJqLGE

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to modify the style object (which only reflects the styles set via the `style` attribute, not via stylesheets), so it's not set there for it to be removed. You can override it by setting it back to the [default value of `scroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment).

```
header.style.backgroundAttachment='scroll';
```

Answer (score 0):

`none` isn't a valid value for the [`background-attachment`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp) property.

Also, that's not how you'd use [`removeProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/removeProperty). It's not a method of `style`.

What you could do though is either set it to a blank value of you're trying to remove the property from an inline style, like:

```
header.style.backgroundAttachment = '';
```

Or you could set it to the initial value, if you've set it something else in a stylesheet, like:

```
header.style.backgroundAttachment = 'initial';
```

Or just set it to another specific value, similar to above.

Comment: Would I use it like this instead?  header.removeProperty('background-attachment')

Comment: `removeProperty` is a method on the style element itself, not the DOM element that is being modified by the style. So you'd actually look for the right rule within the right stylesheet by index like `document.styleSheets[0].rules[0].style` (which is super brittle). And after all that, you're actually removing it from the CSS completely, not as a temporary state. So that's why I suggested the methods I did above.